Invalid SuiteQL request body parameter q
I am new to NetSuite and its API and running into a a bit of an odd one.
When I use Postman to extract data from NetSuite api with suiteQL I am able to successfully establish the connection and return results (200 OK)
When I try to run the same suiteQL query from by application using JavaScript I get the following error:

"Invalid SuiteQL request. Provide a valid SuiteQL query in the request body parameter q."

Here is what I have tried in the JavaScript that is yielding the error
var record_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchURL,{
   'method': 'POST',
   "Content-Type" : "application/json",
   "prefer":"transient",
   headers: {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer "+ access_token
  },
   body: {
   "q" : "SELECT email, COUNT(*) as count FROM transaction GROUP BY email"
  },
 
  'muteHTTPExceptions':true
 });

not sure where I am going wrong between the two environments.
I have also tried setting up the query as a variable with JSON.stringigy and then calling that in the body, but it also errors out.
var query = JSON.stringify({
  "q": "SELECT email, COUNT(*) as count FROM transaction GROUP BY email"
  });

var record_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchURL,{
   'method': 'POST',
   "Content-Type" : "application/json",
   "prefer":"transient",
   headers: {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer "+ access_token
  },
   body: {
   query
  },

  'muteHTTPExceptions':true
 });

Any help will be greatly appreciated
